# What is the cardinality of the set of all explicit functions?

Tags: functions, set-theory, infinity

I was just wondering the number of all explicit functions , whatever it is continuous or discontinuous, or it has a graph or not.

As far as I know, it seems that $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ which denotes all functions from reals from reals has a cardinality of $\aleph_2 $, with my attempt like 
$$card(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})=\aleph_1 ^{\aleph_1 } =2^{\aleph_0 \cdot 2^{\aleph_0 }}<2^{2^{2^{\aleph }}}=\aleph_3 $$
If we accepted GCH (the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis) the result followed trivially.
But when it comes to "all" functions with no description of domain, I have literally no idea.

Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't $\aleph_0 \cdot 2^{\aleph_0}= 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: @Ranc Ummm... I've considered this, but I'm not really sure for a elegant proof, so I chose to use a greater tool.

Comment: What is your definition of an "implicit function"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm sorry I want to say an explicit function at first and my brain experienced short circuit

Comment: @user8012403 (Partially off-topic): To see that $\aleph_0 \cdot 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0$, consider the product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}$, then the $n$th  copy of $\mathbb{R}$ can be put injectively in $(n,n+1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, that shows that  $\aleph_0 \cdot 2^{\aleph_0} \leq \aleph_0$.

Comment: For any cardinality $\kappa$ we have:$$\kappa^\kappa\leq (2^\kappa)^\kappa=2^{\kappa\times\kappa}=2^\kappa.$$

Comment: $|\mathbb{R}|$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$. The statement $|\mathbb{R}| = \aleph_1$ is the continuum hypothesis, which is indecidable in ZFC.